# .NetCore Angular: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line 0, position 0." during Angular PUT request alone

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing a simple new web using asp.net core 2.2 and angular 8.
I always get

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, 
statusText: "Bad Request", url: "https://localhost:5001/api/session/1", 
ok: false, …}
    error:
    detail: "The inputs supplied to the API are invalid"
    errors:
    "": ["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '',         
    line 0, position 0."]
```

When I try making a request via postman to my back-end everything seems ok.

```
**public async Task<Session> UpdateSession(Session session)
    {
        if(session == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Session not found");
        }
        _db.Sessions.Update(session);
        var saved = false;
        while (!saved)
        {
            try
            {
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                saved = true;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry.Entity is Session)
                    {
                        var prosposedValue = entry.CurrentValues;
                        var databaseValue = entry.GetDatabaseValues();
                        foreach (var property in 
 - prosposedValue.Properties)
                           {
                               var prosposedValues = 
prosposedValue[property];
                               var databaseValues = 
databaseValue[property];
                           }
                           entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValue);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           throw new NotSupportedException(
                               "Don't know how to handle consurrency 
conflicts for "
                               + entry.Metadata.Name);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           return session;
       }

  [HttpPut("{sessionId}")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSession([FromBody] Session 
 session)
       {
           try
           {
               if (ModelState.IsValid)
               {
                   if (session.id > 0)
                   {
                       await context.UpdateSession(session);
                       return Ok();
                   }
                   return BadRequest();
               }
               else
               {
                   throw new InvalidOperationException();
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

               throw new NullReferenceException(ex.Message.ToString());
           }
       }

 updateSession(id:number, session: Cl_session) {

   const Id = `${this.url}/${id}`;
   return this.http.put<Cl_session>(Id, Cl_session)
               .pipe(
                 catchError(this.appConfig.handleError)
               );   }

   if(this.mysession.id) {
       this.isLoading = true;
       console.log(this.mysession);  // using this printed the values in 
 the console
       this._session.updateSession(this.mysession.id, 
 this.mysession).subscribe(()=> {
        this.message = "Session updated successfully";
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.router.navigate(['/session/list']);
        }, 500);
       }, (error) =>{
         console.log(error);
         //this.appConfig.handleError(error);
       });**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors like "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line 0, position 0." are almost invariably JSON parse errors, usually caused when the string that's being deserialized is not actually valid JSON. There's not enough of your client-side code here to properly diagnose what the actual cause is, but look at the value of `Cl_session`.

Comment: i get this when i console.log(Cl_session) in chrome console  {id: 1, sessionName: "2019/202023", startDate: "2019-05-31T00:00:00"}

Comment: You are correct. You really save my day. I was passing the Cl_session are parameter directly in the angular PUT i.e  

    updateSession(id:number, session: Cl_session): Observable<Cl_session> {
    const Id = `${this.url}/${id}`;
    return this.http.put<Cl_session>(Id, Cl_session)  // this is where the error was
      .pipe(
      catchError(this.appConfig.handleError)
      );
      }